# DateAndTime.DateDiff not working

Tags: c#, datetime

I am passing the right parameters to the `DateAndTime.DateDiff(Internval, Date1,Date2)` but I am getting No Overload for method `DateDiff` takes 3 arguments.

```
private void CloseRegister()
{
     try
     {
     GetTransactionNumberFromRegMst();
     SeqNum = 1;
     TransDate = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Convert.ToDateTime("12/28/1800"), DateTime.Now);
     TransTime = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Now) * 100;

     WriteCshTServClose();
     WriteTranServClose();

     UpdateRegMstWithTransactionNumber();
     UpdateNetRegsStatus(7);
     UpdateTillSeqSequence(TillSeqSequence + 1);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     string close = "CloseRegister";
     logger.AddEntry(TFSUtilities.Logger.EventType.Info, "frmMain.CloseRegister", "Exception", ref ex);
     AbendProgram(ref close, ref ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: Let me know about your requirement in short/ What you are trying to achieve

Comment: @un-lucky I am tring to get the difference in days between (12/28/1800) and  now?

Comment: You should just be able to subtract them from each other directly.  The subtraction operator is overloaded for dates to return a `TimeSpan`. `var days = (time1 - time2).TotalDays;`

Comment: The method has 5 parameters.  You can only type 3 if you use VS2010 or higher.  Or add 1, 1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (even though it is a C# app) in your application by adding a reference.  Then your code should work fine:

e.g.

```
long TransTime =
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateDiff(
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Second, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Now) * 100;
```

With VS 2010 and forward you can leave off the optional parameters.

Also, make sure `TransTime` and `TransDate` are `long`.

Helpful [reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81806efe-f565-4444-8b94-f3332d29efc6/datediff-calculation-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral):

Answer (score 0):

The Better option for you to get the Date Difference in Days is the following. You can directly subtract one date From another and then use [`.TotalDays();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string inputString = "12/28/1800";
DateTime TransDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out TransDate))
{
    double differenceInDays = (DateTime.Now - TransDate).TotalDays;
    double differenceInHours = (DateTime.Now - TransDate).TotalHours;
}
else
{ 
   // Your input is not valid
}
```

> **Note :-** The [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) will Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime
>   equivalent. *The format of the string representation must match a
>   specified format exactly*. The method returns a value that indicates
>   whether the conversion succeeded.

Include `using System.Globalization;` for `CultureInfo`